# SSIS XML Task XSLT operation not producing an error

Tags: xslt, ssis, ssis-2008

The XML Task XSLT operation requires a Source, a Destination (when SaveOperationResult=True), and a Second Operand.  The Destination is of type file connection.

Here is my issue:  if the filepath provided for the destination is not valid, the task does not error.  In other words, it did not successfully write the operation result to a destination.  SSIS then moves on to the next task, which will error because it depends on the output of the XML Task. This error does not describe the problem accurately. Does anyone know how to force an error in the XML Task XSLT operation if the output destination is not valid?  This is SSIS 2008 R2.

We have an event handler for the OnError event. The event is not being raised.

Comment: How about adding an Even Handler for the `OnError` event...it can be an script task or anything that suit your needs

Comment: Thank you, I failed to mention that we have the OnError event handler in use.  The event is not being raised.  I'll edit my question.

Comment: So, maybe a better solution is include an script task before the xml task that validates the source or the destination, and trigger an exception from there...

Comment: A colleague and I came to a similar conclusion just a few minutes ago. We are placing a script task to check for the working file after the xml task, since this is the most useful placement for this particular situation.  The best thing is having the XML Task itself error out, but glad to hear you're thinking this is a viable workaround as well.

Comment: Glad to help @Rick